# bug spamming gmail contacts

Tags: gmail, spoofing

So I'm completely out of my element here. I don't even know where to begin solving this.  Two times in the past couple of days I have gotten long lists of mail delivery subsystem messages on my primary gmail account with delivery status notification (failure) tags on them.

It seems I have encountered some sort of bug/virus/spoof/who knows what, that is taking large samples of my gmail address book and sending mass emails with links such as this: `http://jivopiji.t35.com/`

(I haven't clicked on this and wouldn't recommend clicking on it but if this helps with solving the problem then great.)

this is the original message as reported by google (with personal info blocked out)

```
Return-Path: <**MYEMAILADDRESS**>
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of **MYEMAILADDRESS** designates 10.216.180.200 as permitted sender) client-ip=10.216.180.200;
Authentication-Results: mr.google.com; spf=pass (google.com: domain of **MYEMAILADDRESS** designates 10.216.180.200 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=**MYEMAILADDRESS**; dkim=pass header.i=**MYEMAILADDRESS**
Received: from mr.google.com ([10.216.180.200])
       by 10.216.180.200 with SMTP id j50mr6599797wem.36.1285022292847 (num_hops = 1);
       Mon, 20 Sep 2010 15:38:12 -0700 (PDT)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
       d=gmail.com; s=gamma;
       h=domainkey-signature:mime-version:received:received:date:message-id
        :subject:from:to:content-type;
       bh=8qvx2NI5Ulhx89ITpuKfFzjpHFP4R/nUOrFBKKUsxj0=;
       b=Fc9gjiUs/tLwDDI0zAujXDEZfjU8OT7AxffW5YyDnNOUW1GGKG1zip+gjLYP7bOaZ8
        BUsWiIN5od5mX60/WRRzqqJNH3lD8zhbjqjDDNWpfWwzPl8frecE2WBi+Vkuv91/BUVo
        /0LqZr7hv9zhGSexnYQEi4y1ruuJP7QeHZVwA=
DomainKey-Signature: a=rsa-sha1; c=nofws;
       d=gmail.com; s=gamma;
       h=mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to:content-type;
       b=g+YoaI2+okNKcEPtKs/oKpKgH0VPYqO9Z/9PzoIyptFov76oRSeesoy1HPhOUoUqu/
        4v7GEslG1zklkeXCUybneVTSf7Dbr5fFy4S3q2ETumMebQwAPC7VRwBGZkyOUr0+RVUP
        LTMP3R98RgQRTHc0R3fR+mdcb1n9gPtE+Bxfw=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Received: by 10.216.180.200 with SMTP id j50mr4928335wem.36.1285022292817;
 Mon, 20 Sep 2010 15:38:12 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.216.134.93 with HTTP; Mon, 20 Sep 2010 15:38:12 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Mon, 20 Sep 2010 17:38:12 -0500
Message-ID: <AANLkTi=G5OnKxRoSNp++T4ScXUwMndok-ov88b4rG0O+@mail.gmail.com>
Subject:
```

any known way to end this spoofing? what are my options here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like anyone can put your home address on a letter and send it out to someone else, they can do the same with an email. In the grand scheme of things, there really isn't a lot you can do to prevent this. You only need to worry when it actually does come from your email address because that means your account has been compromised.
You should run scans on your computer just to make sure that nothing has set itself up to spam from your computer using your credentials. Change your email password as well.

Comment: so this is one of my many confusions regarding this.  Since the delivery failure messages are being sent to me, I would have assumed that the messages were being sent from my account. Incorrect?

Comment: Incorrect. It's just like if someone sent out prank letters with your return address on the envelope. Email headers aren't secure, they'll be whatever the sender wants them to be.